# Javascript: How to un-disable buttons when 'back' button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have buttons, that upon being clicked, will take the user to another page, and before doing so, will become disabled

```
$(this).prop('disabled',true);
```

When the user clicks on the 'back' button on some browsers (e.g. Firefox and iOS Safari), the button will still be disabled. I'd like the button to continue to be disabled upon click, but then to be NOT disabled if the user returns to the page (whether it's by the 'back' button or other means). How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What browsers are doing this? Are you also using jquerymobile or a similar library that interferes with the browser history, the back button or uses the #-symbol for navigation?

Comment: If the button take a user to another page, why at all disabled them?

Comment: @LGSon because it takes a while for the javascript code to process before it can take the user to the next page. While it's processing I want to prevent the user from clicking the button again

Comment: Then I think it is better if you present that as the issue, so you can take full control of the process, as I'm sure there is a much better solution, than be dependent on how the browser decides to deal with it, and especially since it is clear they behave different.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable buttons when document is ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "button" ).prop( 'disabled', false );
});
```

Comment: Thanks; however this isn't triggered when the 'back' feature is used eg on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

adding
`window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {});` will force Firefox to behave like Chrome:

```js
const appEl = document.body;
const buttonEl = document.createElement("button");
buttonEl.textContent = "button";
buttonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const pEl = document.createElement("p");
  pEl.textContent = "changing page in 1 sec";
  appEl.append(pEl);
  setTimeout(() => (window.location = "//example.com"), 1000);
  buttonEl.disabled = true;
});
appEl.append(buttonEl);

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {});
```